# Capturing client side validation message in selenium (testng)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

[image: site image]I want to capture the message (diplayed in form of text) which is generated after I enter invalid input in the textbox. This message is displayed when I click on other textbox or simply on the screen. This text has the id assigned to it, but gets displayed on run time when invalid input is entered, otherwise its not displayed.

This is the line of code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_CenterCPH_txtCityName")).sendKeys(c.cityname);
```

As,I'm passing multiple input using @dataProvider in testng, so I may have both positive and negative results.So in case of negative result I want to capture the error message generated runtime at client side and the later fetch it to the report.As of now I'm only able to fetch the server-side error message, getting difficulty in fetching the client side error messages.

I have attached the images of the view source of the site,

Thanks in advance
the site image[image: view source of the site]

Comment: where is the view source image

Comment: I have added just now @rajNishKuMar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi please do it like below

```
public class CapturingErrorMessage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("ur url");

        // suppose u entered wrong i.e more then 128 character string in the input box

        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_CenterCPH_txtCityName")).sendKeys("more then 128 character");

        // talking under consideration that error message is displayed when you click on other textbox or simply on the screen.

        // suppose below line is to click on other option or some where on the screen 
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_CenterCPH_txtCityName")).click();

        // now error message comes so before capturing the error message firstly try to 
        // identify if the span id with error message is present or not

        // simply in the if i am checking that if the size of the span tag with error is more then 0 or not if more then zero 
        // i.e error is present on the page
        if(driver.findElements(By.id("ct100_CenterCPH_revAlphaNum1Len")).size() > 0){
            String error = driver.findElements(By.id("ct100_CenterCPH_revAlphaNum1Len")).get(0).getText();
            System.out.println(error);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Element not present :  no error message");
        }   
    }
    }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks alot, I had missed one click event, thats why it wasnt working

Comment: It happens some time anyways i am happy it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve it like this using **ExpectedConditions.not.invisibilityOfElementWithText**  because using **presenceOf** would return true regardless of visibility on DOM or not:

```
public static final By INVALID_CITY_NAME = 
   By.xpath(".//span[ends-with(@id,'CenterCPH_txtCityName");
  ...
public static boolean waitForTextToAppear(String textToAppear, By locator,
   int timeoutSeconds)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,timeoutSeconds);
    return wait.until(
       ExpectedConditions.not.invisibilityOfElementWithText(locator, textToAppear)
    );
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
boolean visible = waitForTextToAppear(INVALID_CITY_NAME, "Invalid City name.", 10);
```

I haven't tried this but I think it will work.  If not, a small adjustment to the code should fix it.